# Code block after numbered list: Markdown bug?

Tags: support, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code blocks after a list, but not within a list in markdown. Is it possible?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34292/code-blocks-after-a-list-but-not-within-a-list-in-markdown-is-it-possible)

Can't add a code block after an ordered list. Example:

1. This is a list item.

   This should be a code block, not part of the list.

Comment: I have the same issue with you...The code block can not be recognized by the editor.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is a list item.

```
This should be a code block, not part of the list.
```

Comment: It does not look very nice, as code block should be aligned with list item.