# Why doesn't CTRL+K work around list/code conflicts?

Tags: support, markdown, ease-of-use

[Ordered List and Code Formatting Conflict](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80248/ordered-list-and-code-formatting-conflict) contains a nice workaround for code/list conflicts. Why doesn't CTRL+K always inject a hidden HTML comment just in case this conflicts occurs?

**UPDATE**: I don't think an HTML comment is sufficient. If you type a list, code followed by the rest of the list the numbers after the code get reset. [How to nest code within a list using Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown) seems to contain the only complete workaround. So the updated question is, why doesn't CTRL+K insert 8 spaces or why doesn't Stackoverflow markup find a way to hide this implementation detail under the hood?