# Bug in markdown viewer with lists and code blocks

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code blocks after a list, but not within a list in markdown. Is it possible?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34292/code-blocks-after-a-list-but-not-within-a-list-in-markdown-is-it-possible)

First, this is not the same as discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown) because the use case is slightly different, I don't want the code to be shown as an item in the list.

---

1. Anyway, this is the bug I just noticed.
2. As expected, the list works as it should.

   But having a code block here
   with multiple lines, I might add
   doesn't behave as expected.

   ```
   I know about the 8 spaces for indentation
   but this is not what I want to have.
   ```
3. But, if I add a single character right after the list wrapped with newlines before and after
4. (As an example I'm using a comma here)

,

```
The code = Block("appears", "just") as expected;
#with ($colors && $everything)
```

1. Also note that the numbering of the list keeps going from one to four while I'd expect it to go 1,2 - 1,2 - 1.
2. In conclusion, seems like code block indented with four spaces isn't considered as a list terminator.

Comment: See [Code block after numbered list: Markdown bug?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25368/code-block-after-numbered-list-markdown-bug) (which seems to have been closed for the wrong reason) and [Code blocks after a list, but not within a list in markdown. Is it possible?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34292/code-blocks-after-a-list-but-not-within-a-list-in-markdown-is-it-possible)

Comment: See also [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3327). (This is the oldest duplicate I could find.)

Answer (score 1):

12. Because 4 spaces
    is used to span list over

    paragraphs and lines.

    24. And the list runs from
        1 to 4 since that is how

        a standard `<li>` works.
13. These are all described

    in the [editing help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and
    [Markdown reference](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list).

```
You can cheat with a
pair of <b></b> tags, but it
is an ugly hack.
```

Comment: That's unfortunate, because it's not what I want. I think that adding two linefeeds to end the list before the code block should work to get around this.